# Confused on how the multiple variables work and how to get all 4 values from 1st item in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
testdata = ["One,For,The,Money", "Two,For,The,Show", "Three,To,Get,Ready", "Now,Go,Cat,Go"]

#My Code:
def chop(string):
    x = 0
    y = 0
    while x < 5:
        y = string.find(",") + 1
        z = string.find(",", y)
        x = x + 1

    return y, z
#My Code Ends

for i in range(4):
    uno, dos, tres, cuatro = chop(testdata[i])
    print(uno + ":" + dos + ":" + tres + ":" + cuatro)
```

It say I don't have enough values, I previously tried appending similar code to a list and it said I had too many

Comment: What is the expected output and what value are you trying to pass to the `chop` function?

Comment: One:For:The:Money
Two:For:The:Show
Three:To:Get:Ready
Now:Go:Cat:Go (on separate lines)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the `chop()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant figure out why You need to do in that way, but maybe it helps.

```
testdata = ["One,For,The,Money", "Two,For,The,Show",
        "Three,To,Get,Ready", "Now,Go,Cat,Go"]

for i in testdata:
    uno, dos, tres, cuatro = i.split(',')
    print(uno + ":" + dos + ":" + tres + ":" + cuatro)
```

#### Result

```
One:For:The:Money
Two:For:The:Show
Three:To:Get:Ready
Now:Go:Cat:Go
```

Just iterate through array and spllit words by `,`. Result is as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for the position of the `,` (comma) in the given line and apply sweeping technique to insert the words into a list. You were getting too few values as the function was not returning 4 elements that is being extracted in the for loop.

```
testdata = ["One,For,The,Money", "Two,For,The,Show", "Three,To,Get,Ready",
            "Now,Go,Cat,Go"]


# My Code:
def chop(line):
    start_position = 0
    words = []
    for i, c in enumerate(line):
        if c == ",":
            words.append(line[start_position:i])
            start_position = i+1
    words.append(line[start_position:])
    return words


# My Code Ends

for i in range(4):
    uno, dos, tres, cuatro = chop(testdata[i])
    print(uno + ":" + dos + ":" + tres + ":" + cuatro)
```

**Output:**

```
One:For:The:Money
Two:For:The:Show
Three:To:Get:Ready
Now:Go:Cat:Go
```

**Explanation (updated):**

Here we are keeping the start position of each word in the `start_position` variable. `enumerate` method returns a tuple of index and the value in each iteration. We are using the value for checking if it is equal to `,` and the index to chop the word from the line, thus using the `enumerate` method.

**References:**

- [Documentation on `enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Comment: Works! I haven't learned enumerate yet, what does it do?

Comment: Updated the explanation with the reference to `enumerate` method. Hope it helps.

Comment: @KludgyCartoon79 if the solution solves the issue, I will appreciate if you mark it as accepted answer.